# logback configuration error parse integer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I get the following error with the `logback-spring.xml`. `%C` is for class, not sure about {1.} after it.

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ClassOfCallerConverter@436e641b - failed to parse integer string [1.] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1."
```

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="Console"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>    
    
    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <root level="info">        
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>
   
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#class) the conversion `C` takes an integer as an option. So just remove the dot `.` after the number `%C{1.}` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [logback PatternLayout manual](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord), **%C** is the **conversion word** for the fully-qualified class name of the caller issuing the logging request.  This conversion takes an integer as an option to shorten the class name. You should remove dot from %C{**1.**} as the compiler clearly states that it's parsing the option as an integer.